# Getting an error for an Invalid Hook Call in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a contact form, and finished the front end last night. I'm getting this error that says Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I'm still somewhat new to React, so I've been watching a lot of tutorials, but I'm rather stumped at this point. I should also add that I'm building in CodeSandbox, and when the sandbox loads everything looks fine. The error didn't trigger until I added a couple dependencies. Here's the component, in it's entirety:

```js
    import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

class EmailMessage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: ""
    };
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3002/send",
      data: this.state
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === "success") {
        alert("Message Sent.");
        this.resetForm();
      } else if (response.data.status === "fail") {
        alert("Message failed to send.");
      }
    });
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.setState({ name: "", email: "", message: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid="sm">
        <div className="EmailMessage" style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
          <h1>Contact Us</h1>
          <p>
            You've had a chance to learn about us, now let's learn about you and
            your vision...
          </p>
          <form
            id="contact-form"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
            method="POST"
          >
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onNameChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="email"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                rows="5"
                id="message"
                value={this.state.message}
                onChange={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Container>
    );
  }

  onNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  }

  onMessageChange(event) {
    this.setState({ message: event.target.value });
  }
}

export default EmailMessage;
```

Thanks for helping! This website is such a valuable resource!

edit per request, footer component:

```html
import React from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

function Footer() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return (
    <Container fluid="sm">
      <footer style={{ paddingTop: "20", color: "darkOrange" }}>
        <p>Made with Passion at Gingersnap Studios ⓒ {year}</p>
      </footer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the component generating the error? I don't see any hook calls there.

Comment: I'm sure. I'm looking at it right now though and it seems to be operating fine. I have a feeling CodeSandbox is just buggy sometimes.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Footer component?

Comment: Done, I can add index.js file as well if you need to look at it. The error I was getting was pointing to an issue using ReactDOM.render().

Comment: Weird well I don't see any React hooks calls so not sure where this error would be coming from. Maybe the react bootstrap Container component but that's doubtful... double check all of your components to see if there are any React hooks calls that you might have missed (e.g. `React.useEffect()`, `React.useState()` etc.)